# Text file-based sequential url rotator isn't working

Tags: php, rotation, text-files

I'm trying to create a text file-based sequential url rotator by using the following code ([original source](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10301271-Sequential-url-rotator&p=10625168&viewfull=1#post10625168)):

```
<?php
$linksfile ="urlrotator.txt";
$posfile = "pos.txt";

$links = file($linksfile);
$numlinks = count($linksfile);

$fp = fopen($posfile, 'r+') or die("Failed to open posfile");
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$num = fread($fp, 1024);
if($num<$numlinks-1) {
  fwrite($fp, $num+1);
} else {
  fwrite($fp, 0);
}
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);

header("Location: {$links[$num]}");
?>
```

After my testing, I found that it keeps appending new position number as a string after the existing content of pos.txt and thus the script only works at the first time.

I tried adding the following line of code before the `if else` statement in order to clear the existing content of pos.txt before updating it.

```
file_put_contents($posfile, "");
```

But then error ocurred at the line of redirection saying `Undefined index: ......` .

Where could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Is it set in a loop? or do you call it multiple times in a row?

Comment: @JulienLachal Sorry, but I don't quite get it. The first time I tested, it worked and redirected me to the correct location, but the subsequent times didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem comes from the mode you are using. When you say

> After my testing, I found that it keeps appending new position number as a string after the existing content of pos.txt and thus the script only works at the first time.

it points me to the mode usage of [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

The mode you should use is `w`, as it will "replace" the content of what is inside `pos.txt`.

```
$fp = fopen($posfile, 'w') or die("Failed to open posfile");
```

Doing so will prevent your from accessing what was in `pos.txt`. So you need to have something like this:

```
$num = file_get_contents($posfile);
$fp = fopen($posfile, 'w') or die("Failed to open posfile");
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
if($num<$numlinks-1) {
  fwrite($fp, $num+1);
} else {
  fwrite($fp, 0);
}
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps! I also found that the `count($linksfile)` in the fourth line of the original code should be `count($links)` instead.